# Create bordered bootstrap cols with margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I have bootstrap bordered columns with margin?

I have:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
  <div class="drag-block" id="addressField_1" ondragover="return dragOver(event)" draggable="true" ondragend="return dragEnd(event)" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)">
  .....................
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkcvpf10/)

But I want

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 drag-block" id="addressField_1" ondragover="return dragOver(event)" draggable="true" ondragend="return dragEnd(event)" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)">
.....................
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9ww5bx1/)

and to look like the first one.

Comment: adding margin to bootstrap cols will cause unwanted block jumps on div class col-*, you must put into a div class=container to get this result (regarding a full page) Try it and tell me if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Just change the css to the following :

```
.drag-block{
    border: 2px dashed #bbb7b7;
    margin: 0px 15px 30px 15px;
    padding: 10px 15px 15px 15px;
    cursor: move;
}
```

Comment: The second column is not going (float) behind the first one (the responsive).